# How should I store the thumb image urls of video in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have to fetch data of videos from local video tube site.

My problem I have no idea how I should store the thumb image urls of video in the database.

I have to import about 700.000 videos and each videos have 8 thumb images. I am afraid using a separate table for the thumb images, because it will be very large. Approx 5.600.000 rows will be in and I am worry about the performance.

Do you have any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that fetching images is best done with `<img src=...>` which works well with a URL for the image.  Yes, the 'src' could be a program that fetches from the database, but is is *usually* more complex and slower.

So, do not put the images in the database; put them in the file system on your web server.  Then put the url in the database.  Better yet, put only the significant part of the url in the database, then construct the rest when building the 'img' tag.

There are 4 (maybe more) ways to display the images:

```
<img src=url-to-file>  -- see above
<img src=program-to-generate-or-load-image>  -- see above
<img src=data:image/jpg;base64,base64-bytes-of-image>
Some kind of Javascript+AJAX to do one of the above "on the fly"
```

I have done all three; with a few dozen thumbnails on a single web page, there is probably little difference in perceived performance.  With hundreds of thumbnails, the three approaches are still competitive.  YMMV.

If you show thousands of images on one page, the client browser will be the slowest part.

For "infinite scroll" I assume you need Javascript+AJAX.